# Faster alternative to DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I parse a string into a DateTime millions of times:

```
public static CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{      
      line = reader.ReadLine();
      string[] fields = line.Split(' ');
      DateTime newDT = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[0], "yyyyMMddTHHmmssfff", ci);
}
```

My profiler highlights ParseExact as being a huge part of time taken. Is there any other method/approach that could parse the string into a DateTime that would be faster?

FOLLOW UP1:

1) I tried this - but speed was same

```
bool OK = DateTime.TryParseExact(fields[0], "yyyyMMddTHHmmssfff", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,out DT);
```

2)

I tried to code my own parser - but this too was as slow:

```
public static DateTime fastParse(ref string s)
{
           return new DateTime(int.Parse(s.Substring(0,4)), int.Parse(s.Substring(4,2)),int.Parse(s.Substring(6,2)), int.Parse(s.Substring(9,2)),int.Parse(s.Substring(11,2)),int.Parse(s.Substring(13,2)),int.Parse(s.Substring(15, 3)));
}
```

FOLLOW UP2

I tried Master117 suggestion of storing values - AGAIN it is NO faster - perhaps the issue is the construction?

```
     public class fastParseData
        {
            int year;
            int mon;
            int day;
            int hour;
            int min; 
            string previousSlice = "";

            public DateTime fastParse(ref string s)
            {
                if (previousSlice != s.Substring(0, 12))
                {
                     year=int.Parse(s.Substring(0,4));
                     mon=int.Parse(s.Substring(4,2));
                     day=int.Parse(s.Substring(6,2));
                     hour= int.Parse(s.Substring(9,2));
                     min = int.Parse(s.Substring(11,2));
                     previousSlice = s.Substring(0, 12);
                }

                return new DateTime(year, mon, day, hour,min, int.Parse(s.Substring(13, 2)), int.Parse(s.Substring(15, 3)));
            }

        }
```

FOLOW UP3

```
                public class fastParseData
                {
                    int year;
                    int mon;
                    int day;
                    int hour;
                    int min; 
                    string previousSlice = "";
                    DateTime previousDT;

                    public DateTime fastParse(ref string s)
                    {
                        if (previousSlice != s.Substring(0, 12))
                        {
                             year=int.Parse(s.Substring(0,4));
                             mon=int.Parse(s.Substring(4,2));
                             day=int.Parse(s.Substring(6,2));
                             hour= int.Parse(s.Substring(9,2));
                             min = int.Parse(s.Substring(11,2));
                             previousSlice = s.Substring(0, 12);
                            previousDT = new DateTime(year, mon, day, hour,min,0,0);
                        }
                        return previousDT.AddMilliseconds((int.Parse(s.Substring(13, 2))*1000)+int.Parse(s.Substring(15, 3)));
                    }

                }
```

FOLLOW UP4

From my profiler the crux seems to be

```
int.Parse(s.Substring(13, 2))
```

With the Parse bit being more costly than the substring.

I tried

```
int.TryParse(s.Substring(13, 2),NumberStyles.None,ci, out secs)
Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(13, 2));
```

but again - no difference in speed.

Is there a faster way to parse an int?

Comment: Are the dates in the fields repeat them self?

Comment: Is that the entire loop? You parse the string into a `DateTime` object and then immediately overwrite it with the next one? It might help if you provided a bit more of your code, i.e. what you're actually doing with the parsed `DateTime`.

Comment: Since it's a fixed format you could try extracting and converting the parts yourself.

Comment: Have a look at http://blog.joachim.at/?p=42

Comment: @V4Vendetta Thansk - Itried it but TryParseExact not faster for me

Comment: It could very well be that most Time is consumed by the DateTime constructor. That would be very hard to optimize.

Comment: try timing parsing of string to int separately and `DateTime` constructor call, if its the constructor than as Henk said before, it would be difficult to optimize

Comment: @Henk. Yes it is starting to look like it is the construction. Is there any other way to create a DateTime?

Comment: use your last time created DateTime and add the time since your last update with addSecond etc

Comment: @Master117 - but then you have to handle all the (1000/60/60/24/28|29|30|31) overflows

Comment: @HenkHolterman you are correct, even though that might still be faster it would be a lot of useless work, therefore i edited my answer

Comment: @Master117: going back to the original question: exactly how much time is it taking  to parse your dates?  It's obvious that from the code you posted, the parsing will be taking the most time - but you've never said *how much* time it's taking or why that's too much.

Comment: @Dan Puzey wrong Person ;)

Comment: Sorry, must have autocompleted wrong! @ManInMoon: see my question above...

Answer (score 9):

The idea of splitting the string is on the right track, but substring is slow.  Whenever I split a string, I use the character accessor. 
yyyyMMddTHHmmssfff
Disclaimer: T

```
public class DateParser1
{
    private static System.String DateFormat="yyMMddTHHmmssfff";

    public static System.DateTime GetDate(System.String SourceString, int Offset=0) // Offset eliminates need for substring
    {
        int Year=0;
        int Month=0;
        int Day=0;
        int Hour=0;
        int Minute=0;
        int Second=0;
        int HourOffset=0;
        int MS=0;
        if(SourceString.Length+Offset<DateFormat.Length) throw new System.Exception(System.String.Format("Date Too Short {0} For {0}",SourceString.Substring(Offset),DateFormat));
        for(int i=0;i<DateFormat.Length;i++)
        {
            System.Char c=SourceString[Offset+i];
            switch(DateFormat[i])
            {
                  case 'y':
                      Year=Year*10+(c-'0');
                      break;
                  case 'M':
                      Month=Month*10+(c-'0');
                      break;
                  case 'd':
                      Day=Day*10+(c-'0');
                      break;
                  case 'T':
                      if(c=='p'||c=='P')
                           HourOffset=12;
                      break;
                  case 'h':
                      Hour=Hour*10+(c-'0');
                      if(Hour==12) Hour=0;
                      break;
                  case 'H':

                      Hour=Hour*10+(c-'0');
                      HourOffset=0;
                      break;
                  case 'm':
                      Minute=Minute*10+(c-'0');
                      break;
                  case 's':
                      Second=Second*10+(c-'0');
                      break;
                  case 'f':
                      MS=MS*10+(c-'0');
                      break;
            }

        }
        if(Year>30) //Change For Your Business Rules
        {
               Year+=1900;
        }
        else
        {
               Year+=2000;
        }
        try
        {
            return new System.DateTime(Year,Month,Day,Hour+HourOffset,Minute,Second,MS);
        }
        catch(System.Exception)
        {
            throw new System.Exception(System.String.Format("Error In Date: {0}/{0}/{0} {0}:{0}:{0}.{0} - {0} {0}",Year,Month,Day,Hour+HourOffset,Minute,Second,MS,DateFormat,SourceString.SubString(Offset,DateFormat.Length)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DanPuzey If you still haven't got around to it these are the mumbers :)


`Starting framework parse for 1000000 iterations...DONE in 2915.00 millis`
`Starting JB parse for 1000000 iterations...DONE in 100.00 millis`

I'll post the benchmark code in an answer below

Comment: Well done : it reminds me finite state machine code ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own parsing algorithm, frist you split your string into array/list/whatever and then use the Datetime Constructor to create your Datetime,

```
DateTime newDT = DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32);
```

since the Year/Month/Day won't change that fast you can BUffer them and have therefore a  lower number of String operations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/system.datetime.aspx

an easy way would be too store the first 8 letters, like string a = fields[0].slice(0,8) (don't know the correct operation at the moment), now you parse them and make the ints, but in the next run you slice them again and test if a = new a, if so use the ints from last time instead of parsing them again, naturally for that you need to store a and the integers

So since now the problem seems to be the Construction time you should try to either add the elapsed time, by checking if your ints are higher/lower than before  with addSecond etc, or you could take your construct and set the values to your new time.

try this:

```
            public class fastParseData
            {
                int year;
                int mon;
                int day;
                int hour;
                int min; 
                string previousSlice = "";
                DateTime previousDT;

                public DateTime fastParse(ref string s)
                {
                    if (previousSlice != s.Substring(0, 12))
                    {
                         year=int.Parse(s.Substring(0,4));
                         mon=int.Parse(s.Substring(4,2));
                         day=int.Parse(s.Substring(6,2));
                         hour= int.Parse(s.Substring(9,2));
                         min = int.Parse(s.Substring(11,2));
                         previousSlice = s.Substring(0, 12);
                         previousDT = new DateTime(year, mon, day, hour,min,0,0);
                    }
                    return previousDT.ParseExact(year, mon, day, hour,min, int.Parse(s.Substring(13, 2)), int.Parse(s.Substring(15, 3));
                }

            }
```

That way you only ones create a DT and then just set the time new

Comment: I created fastParse as you suggest (see follow up above) I don't understand your idea about buffer though? Surely you would need to test if Year is same (another operation) but would still need to do the construction again anyway. Can you explain a bit more please

Comment: an easy way would be too store the first 8 letters, like string a = fields[0].slice(0,8) or so, now you parse them and make the ints, but in the next run you slice them and test if a = new a, if so use the ints from last time instead of parsing them again

Comment: +1, nice idea indeed, and I think @ManInMoon, can use a `Dictionary<string,int>` for holding year, month, and day part, or even construct a dictionary or multiple dictionaries (for year, month, day), and then get the integer value based on the key *(string)*, but this will reduce the time for string to int parsing, not sure if that is the main reason though

Comment: @Master117 See FOLLOW UP2. Is this what you mean? Unfortunately, it does NOT speed things up.

Comment: it obviously does speed up, but ONLY on the second run and later, you have to do a lot less parsing, what you can't speed up is the constructor of DateTime, if that is the thing taking up mose time well, then you need a copletly different approach

Comment: @Master117. See FOLLOW UP3. Here I am adding secs and ms. to previous DateTime. Again, the timing is almost exactly the sam (I am doing a big test that takes about 20secs by the way). Nothing I have tried so far even dents this time. BUT I need to end up with a DateTime.

Comment: _That way you only ones create a DT ..._ - That's not what really happens. DateTime is an immutable Value type.

Comment: And `DateTime.ParseExact` is static, too, so creating an instance or not makes no difference (in fact, if anything, this would be marginally slower).

Comment: Also: what makes you think that this parser is faster than the standard?  Have you profiled this code against the system method?

Comment: @Dan Puzey, i only Speed up the substring  part, which should be clear, Array acces versus String operations.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code used to benchmark [James's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16920747/289992) against the framework code (in reference to my comment there). I run this in Release mode, .Net 4.5.2, 32bit console

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string date = "2015-04-11T12:45:59";
    const string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss";

    var reference = FrameworkParse(date, format);
    var method1 = JamesBarrettParse(date, format);

    if (reference != method1)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("reference date {0} does not match SO date {1}",reference.ToString("s"),method1.ToString("s")));
    }

    const int iterations = 1000000;
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    //FRAMEWORK PARSE
    Console.Write("Starting framework parse for {0} iterations...", iterations);
    sw.Start();
    DateTime dt;
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        dt = FrameworkParse(date, format);
        if (dt.Minute != 45)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("duh");
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("DONE in {0} millis",sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("F2",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    //James Barrett parse
    Console.Write("Starting JB parse for {0} iterations...", iterations);
    sw.Restart();
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        dt = JamesBarrettParse(date, format);
        if (dt.Minute != 45)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("duh");
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("DONE in {0} millis",sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("F2",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    Console.Write("press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static DateTime FrameworkParse(string s, string format, CultureInfo info = null)
{
    var time = DateTime.ParseExact(s, format,
        info ?? CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
    return time;
}
```

Output is

> Starting framework parse for 1000000 iterations...DONE in 2058.00 millis
>   Starting JB parse for 1000000 iterations...DONE in 324.00 millis
>   press any key to exit

Comment: Thanks for this - I have written my own (more generic) version and used this to test it: Starting framework parse for 1000000 iterations...
DONE in 691.00 millis
Starting JB parse for 1000000 iterations...DONE in 219.00 millis
Starting DateTimeConverter parse for 1000000 iterations...DONE in 217.00 millis

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would be any faster, but you could convert your date string into a long and then split it up arithmetically like so:

```
string dateStr = "20131108134701234"; //yyyyMMddHHmmssfff
long dateLong = long.Parse(dateStr);

int f = (int) (dateLong % 1000);
int s = (int) ((dateLong % 100000 - f) / 1000);
int mi = (int) ((dateLong % 10000000 - s - f) / 100000);
int h = (int) ((dateLong % 1000000000 - mi - s - f) / 10000000);
int d = (int) ((dateLong % 100000000000 - h - mi - s - f) / 1000000000);
int mo = (int) ((dateLong % 10000000000000 - d - h - mi - s - f) / 100000000000);
int y = (int) ((dateLong % 100000000000000000 - mo - d - h - mi - s - f) / 10000000000000);

DateTime dateDT = new DateTime(y, mo, d, h, mi, s, f);
```

(naive, unoptimised implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to James Barrett's reply but I think faster because it's more straight fordward:

Let's say you have a date with format yyMMdd.

The fastest way to convert it that I found is:

```
var d = new DateTime(
(s[0] - '0') * 10 + s[1] - '0' + 2000, 
(s[2] - '0') * 10 + s[3] - '0', 
(s[4] - '0') * 10 + s[5] - '0')
```

Just, choose the indexes according to your date format of choice. If you need speed probably you don't mind the 'non-generic' way of the function.

This method takes about 10% of the time required by:

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good place to use parallelization. Parallel.ForEach could be a good one use, but you may want to test other ways of doing parallelization

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetLines(TextReader reader)
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
         yield return reader.ReadLine();
    }
}

private static CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

public static ConcurrentBag ProcessData(TextReader reader)
{
    ConcurrentBag <DateTime> results = new ConcurrentBag <DateTime>();
    char[] seperators = {' '};

    Parallel.ForEach(GetLines(reader), line =>
    {
        //We only need the first field so limit the split to 2
        string[] fields = line.Split(seperators, 2);
        results.Enqueue(DateTime.ParseExact(fields[0], "yyyyMMddTHHmmssfff", ci));
    });

    return results
}
```

The drawback of this is you loose order, if that is important to you there is a version Parallel.ForEach that will [pass in the index from the IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783359.aspx). You would need to store the line number with the date (perhaps a `ConcurrentDictionary<long,DateTime>` or store a `Tuple<long,DateTime>` in the bag) then sort the data at a later point.

Comment: Nice idea, BUT I am already running the maximum number of instances of my code in parallel. So I would just be slowing down the overall throughput - but you are correct it speed up a single run.